# Tkinter: Progressbar indicating the status of the uploaded file

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I'd like to have in my tkinter GUI a progress bar that gives visual cue about the status of the loading of a file. This is my code, but when I launch it the app just get stuck and does not work (I have to close it by force).

```
def start():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Select") 
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file)

    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for i in range(os.path.getsize(file)):
            progressbar["value"] = 5      
            progressbar["maximum"] = filesize
            label.config(text=str(progressbar["value"]) + "%")          
            root.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1) 



label = ttk.Label(root, text="00%")
label.pack()

button_prg = Button(root, text="progress", command=start)
button_prg.pack()

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=100,  mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack()
```

Also is there a way to resize the height of the bar? since I'd like to put it in the status bar at the bottom of my frame. Thank you all!

Comment: What if the file size is big? Referring to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), ```os.path.getsize``` returns size in bytes

Comment: It should always be in mb unit and not more. For now I don't have that problem since my app is not working at all

Comment: Avoid `time.sleep()`.

Comment: @Ame What's the point of the `time.sleep(1)`? Also if you have a long loop you should use `.after` scripts.

Comment: Since the value  of `filesize` doesn't change in your `for` loop — why would you expect that? — so if nothing else that would make it not work the way you probably expect.

Answer (score 1):

well what you want, i didn't understand clearly..
but here's what you shall have:

```py
import time
import os
from tkinter import * #importing * is a very bad habit!
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
def start():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Select") 
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file)

    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for i in range(os.path.getsize(file)):
            progressbar["value"] = progressbar["value"]+1
            progressbar["maximum"] = filesize
            label.config(text=str(int(progressbar["value"]/os.path.getsize(file)*100)) + "%")          
            root.update_idletasks()
            #time.sleep(1) 

root = Tk()

label = ttk.Label(root, text="00%")
label.pack()

button_prg = Button(root, text="progress", command=start)
button_prg.pack()

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=100,  mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

btw, there's a limit in the file size.. that is 400kb.. i am just unable to load any of my files larger than 400kb in size!

Comment: Avoid `.update_idletasks()`. Most of the time it don't help. And in this case the window will still be unresponsive.

Comment: Thank you. It works now but it's painfully slow. is it normal? My file are indeed larger then 400kb sometimes. So it would be better to no use a progress bar?

Comment: the way it works is probably slow.. as when you start it, it does loop for every byte of the file! if file is 389kb, it would do the loop 389000 times! so i can say using a progressbar isn't necessary.. or you can make it such that it repeats for every 10 or 50 bytes.. and make it faster..

Comment: Yes, I just need a way to show my program is running without error. I'll find another way!

Comment: @TheLizzard we can use threads for for unresponsive windows.

Comment: @BerkEfeKeskin Be careful when using threads with `tkinter` as it can crash the python interpreter without a traceback.